# Testing promise with stub

Tags: node.js, chai, sinon, stub, sinon-chai

I'm trying to do some tests with chai using sinon stub. The thing is, I'm stubbing my fetch like this and resolving my promise.

```
  let fetchedStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchedStub = sinon.stub(global, 'fetch');
    fetchedStub.resolves({ json: () => { body: 'json' } });
  });
```

Then I'm testing if my data is returning correctly

```
it('should return the JSON data from the promise', () => {
  const result = search('test');
  result.then((data) => {
    expect(data).to.be.eql({ body: 'json' });
  });
});
```

But instead of passing the test, I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong with my promise? I think I need some light here.

Edit: this is the search function.

```
    export const search = (query) => {
  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${query}&type=artist`)
    .then(data => data.json());
};
```

Comment: Please show the code of `search` function

Comment: It's there on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `search` arrow function does not return anything, hence in your test `result` is undefined, hence the error message.

You should simply *return* the result of your fetch:

```js
export const search = (query) => {
  // return something
  return fetch(`url`).then(data => data.json());
};
```

You *might* have been confused by the arrow function *shorthand* syntax, which automatically returns the result of a single expression, provided that it is *not* wrapped in curly braces:

```js
export const search = (query) => fetch(`url`).then(data => data.json()); // no curly braces after the arrow
```